# PHP MySQL Scope of Temporary Tables

Tags: php, mysql, scope, temp-tables

I have a PHP script which makes users able to search my databases. For these searches, I combine the data in a temporary table.

Let's say I have the following situation:

- User 1 starts searching at 11:12:20 and the search takes 5 seconds to
  perform
- User 2 starts searching at 11:12:24

This means that the temporary table, created for the search of user 1 is still active when user 2 starts to search. Let's say I have a 'solid / hardcoded' script which just states the name of the temporary table as `TempTable`.

Will the situation occur that the Temporary Table named `TempTable` can't be created because for User 2, because User 1 is still using it? Or is MySQL smart enough to assign a Temporary Table to a session?

***So my question in short is: what is the scope of a temporary table?***

Comment: Why do you need a temporary table in the first place?

Comment: As stated in the question, my users are able to search my database**s** and therefore, I combine the data in a temporary table which makes it easier and faster to search through the relevant data since MySQL doesn't have to spool the data of each query-request to the browser / client

Comment: Surely creating a temp table.... Filling it... and then querying it takes longer and is more complicated than just querying the REAL tables

Comment: Also USER2 will never see USER1's temporary tables. They are related to a specific connection.

Comment: _This means that the temporary table, created for the search of user 1 is still active when user 2 starts to search_ **But not visible to or usable by User2**

Comment: @RiggsFolly, this is definitely not true since I benchmarked a lot. Besides that, how do you know what tables in 'merge' into a temp table?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, great so the scope of a Temporary Table is session specific. That's an answer I was looking for and related to the question, thanks